# Can we use ofstream object as a third argument in backtrace_symbols_fd()?

Tags: c++, linux

I have to call `backtrace_symbols_fd()` function, but the third argument of this function is file descriptor.
so can i pass that third argument as ofstream object ?

I'm tyring following code:

```
 ofstream myfile;
 myfile.open ("example.txt");
 size_t size = backtrace(aray, 5000);
 backtrace_symbols_fd(aray, 5000, myfile);
```

But with above function call im getting following error:

```
cannot convert 'std::ofstream' to 'int' for argument '3' to 
'void backtrace_symbols_fd(void* const*, int, int)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, no it is not possible to pass an `ofstream`.
Just use the `open(2)` function to get a file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [crazy little idea](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio) using `shared_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

std::shared_ptr<std::FILE> make_file(const char * filename, const char * flags)
{
  return std::shared_ptr<std::FILE>(std::fopen(filename, flags), std::fclose);
}

int main()
{
  auto fp = make_file("hello.txt", "wb");
  int  fd = fileno(fp.get());

  //...

  backtrace_symbols_fd(aray, 5000, fd);
}
```